# Back button in Navigation bar not displayed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller connected to a popover controller, which directs to a new view controller. I want to add a back button on the navigation item to the last view controller so that when I click back it will return to the first view controller
I tried creating segue and click action in the popover controller and add back button in the segue function/click action function
neither of them works

This is what I do in the Popover. I already present the popover with UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate and this is what PopoverVC looks like. In this way, I add IBAction to enable the click action of the label in popover. I write the backbutton in the IBAction function and create the navigationcontroller with rootview, and the back button doesn't appear.

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    //TODO: add BACK button
    @IBAction func createNewChat(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let contactVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "contacts") as? NewContactsViewController
        let nc2 = UINavigationController()
        let back = UIBarButtonItem()
        back.title = "Back"
        nc2.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back
        nc2.pushViewController(contactVC!, animated: true)
        self.present(nc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I also tried another way, I create a segue in storyboard and connect the popover to the navigation controller, the backbutton still  doesn't appear.The segue is hooked up to the navigation controller in the storyboard.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let seg = segue.destination as! ContactsTableViewController
    let back = UIBarButtonItem()
    back.title = "Back"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back
}
```

My question is: how to make the back button appear? After it appears, how to make it work? I don't want the back button points to the popover, I want the back button will make users return to the VC that creates the popoverVC.

Answer (score 2):

The back button in a navigation bar doesn't belong to THIS view controller; it is the back button item of the *previous* view controller already on the navigation stack. But you have no previous view controller. So just use, like, a left bar button item that says Back, or something.

Thus, give the bar button item (`back`) an `action` and `target` and change

```
nc2.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back
```

to

```
nc2.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back
```

Comment: No problem! I hope this solved the problem; if it did, please _accept_ my answer (checkmark to the left of the answer)